# Ansible group_vars variable precedence (group_vars override other group_vars)

Tags: ansible

On Ansible 2.2,

I have an Ansible hosts file:

```
[webserver]
aegir.dev

[hostmaster]
aegir.dev
```

I have two `group_vars/` files:

```
# group_vars/webserver.yml
my_var:
  - vagrant
```

and

```
# group_vars/hostmaster.yml
my_var:
  - vagrant
  - aegir
```

and the playbook:

```
- hosts: webserver
  tasks:
    - debug: var=my_var

- hosts: hostmaster
  tasks:
    - debug: var=my_var
```

Output:

```
PLAY [webserver] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [aegir.dev]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [aegir.dev] => {
    "my_var": [
        "vagrant",
        "aegir"
    ]
}

PLAY [hostmaster] **************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [aegir.dev]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [aegir.dev] => {
    "my_var": [
        "vagrant",
        "aegir"
    ]
}
```

Why both `webserver` and `hostmaster` use the variables from `hostmaster.yml`?

Probably I'm not using the `group_vars` correctly but how I can fix that?

EDIT

The real case scenario is that I have the same role running on two groups, one is `webserver` that actually contains 4 generic servers and the `hostmaster` group that is a webserver + extra configuration on the same role (the user aegir exists only on aegir.dev and not on the other 3 web-servers)

Comment: Looks broken by design to me. The main problem is, that Ansible has no proper scoping at all. It is the direct consequence of Ansible's idea to build a programming language on top of a JSON data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is a bit old but the mentioned issue already exists, so I wrote my answer to one who needs the answer.

Actually, based on [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged), Ansible focused on the Host and Task, so groups don’t really survive outside of inventory and host matching. To solve this problem, we need to add a prefix to variables of groups (like using namespacing to avoid conflicts).

```yaml
# inventory/hosts.yml
webservers:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
  vars:
    webserver_my_var: ...

hostmaster:
  hosts:
    host1:
  vars:
    hostmaster_my_var: ...
```

And in the playbook, you can use the variable safely.

```yaml
# playbooks/main.yml
- hosts: webserver
  tasks:
    - debug: var=webserver_my_var | mandatory

- hosts: hostmaster
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostmaster_my_var | mandatory
```

This way you will eliminate the problem safely.

Using the same variable name inside multiple groups has another problem. It's hard to guess the value of a variable by just looking at the inventory, you need to know the relation between groups and the order/precedence of one group to another and it is hard work and error-prone.

Comment: Hi @Ocean thank you very much for your reply. I can't test it right now but it looks valid to me. Cheers

Comment: @tvl, I'm really glad that it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 7):

This is expected behaviour. See [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable):

> Within any section, redefining a var will overwrite the previous instance. **If multiple groups have the same variable, the last one loaded wins.** If you define a variable twice in a play’s vars: section, the 2nd one wins.

Comment: Thanks! That's true, but how I can overcome this problem? I don't want to assign them directly in the playbook (after every task) because it will make a mess...

Comment: You have to refactor your variables. But your question lacks use case details to give any advices...

Comment: The real case scenario is that I have the same role running on two groups, one is `webserver` that actually contains 4 generic servers and the `hostmaster` group that is a webserver + extra configuration on the same role (the user aegir exists only on aegir.dev and not on the other 3 web-servers)

Comment: I'd split role into generic and hostmater. Or you can try to adopt something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40280199/2795592) in your role (define what users should be created, based on group names).